# Can I remove payment requirement part of a MIT licensed library

Tags: mit, license, open-source-definition

A library I have used has recently introduced a payment requirement, i.e buy a license code and enter it to be able to use the library. The library is however still MIT licensed. Would it be legal to fork the repo and remove the license check?

Comment: Based on your summary of the situation, yes, that's fine, from a copyright standpoint.  It would be useful to get a link to the library in question, though, so we can check for complications (including, but not limited to, submarine patents).

Comment: https://github.com/nager/Nager.Date

this is the repo in question.

Comment: Not being a programmer, I can't tell if the code in github, which is to say the code under MIT, is the entire server-side implementation, or just client-side code that contacts their server on invocation in order to retrieve the data.  Hopefully, someone more versed in reading code than I can shed more light on this.

Comment: @MadHatter as far as I can tell, all the data is contained in the NuGet package and there is no use of any server-side components. The license key check is also trivial; I won't post the code here but let's just say it's not cryptographically secure ;)

Comment: @PhilipKendall that looks to me like a useful answer; care to write it up as one?

Comment: @MadHatter well, I was waiting for you to write one :) But okay.

Comment: @PhilipKendall it is indeed trivial, I think its more in the style of WinRAR, to encourage donations/contributions - John, if you've supported open source I wouldn't feel guilty at all by "bypassing" it

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In copyright terms, you can make any changes you like to MIT licensed software so long as you ensure that

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

That includes removing any parts of the software you don't like, including any licensing checks. Your case is very odd in that:

- The code in question is fully client-side, it's not that the license key is used to communicate with a server-side component.
- Looking at the code, the "license check" is trivial anyway.
- The author presuambly knows all this.

The most likely possibility here in my opinion is that the author is using this as a very clumsy way of getting donations towards their project. That's legally fine, but I personally think they'd do better just asking for donations.

Comment: Also possible the idea behind this is actually get paid to provide the compiled binaries; which I do *not* find tacky.

Comment: "*With a sponsorship you get the license key to use the variants locally without a dependency to our REST API*" What I think is confusing things is the README is for the Public Holiday API project as a whole, not specifically for the Nager.Date code. You can use their API (which doesn't require a key, but it seems like it may in the future), or if you're using .NET you can use Nager.Date which has the data embedded.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's clumsy, it works rather well. To use the library, you either have to go through the hassle of forking (and maintaining that fork), or through the hassle of buying a licence key. This nudges people towards the second.

Comment: @Bergi when I say the license check is trivial, I really do mean it. You just need to add one line of code to your program with a simple English string.

Comment: @PhilipKendall Oh you mean the implementation is clumsy, not the general approach. Then yeah…

Comment: @PhilipKendall: Have a closer look at the commit that introduced the license check: Apparently, the key is changed to something less trivial at build time. So, yes, you'd have to compile the code yourself to work around that.